# new java table more usefull than JTable

Tags: java, swing

Some days ago I have a glimpse.

With all headache what comes in the moment when need to work with JTable, and recently I have seen the utility of JSplitPane, I think to an idea, but sincere, I don't know exactly where I get to start to reach a good result.

The result that I want, and maybe that will help other people, is a table created with JScrollPane + JPanel + JSplitPane + GridBagLayout + probably others  components, where we hope to can put easily other components like JButton, images or what else we want, because the phisical cells I want to be JPanel.

Here is an example with a respectable list, in my opinion, also find on this forum:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class DynamicPanelList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DynamicPanelList();
    }

    public DynamicPanelList() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new ListPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        });
    }

    public class ListPane extends JPanel {
    private JPanel mainList;
    public ListPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.mainList = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        this.mainList.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(mainList));
        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
        panel.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.GRAY));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        ListPane.this.mainList.add(panel, gbc, 0);
        ListPane.this.validate();
        ListPane.this.repaint();
        }
    });

    add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
    }
}
```

At this code I want to add some features to add header(not very difficult), but the difficult part is to add columns that can be resized. Here is the section where I guess I need to use JSplitPane. If my ideea is wrong, please comment and if you have an ideea, even a small one, please share with us.

Next days, I'll try to add more code here to explain more detailed my idea.

Thanks, and I'm sorry for my "cave" english skill.

Comment: happy time wasting ;-) Seriously, don't you have something more useful to do, like f.i. actually _learning_ how-to use a JTable correctly?

Comment: listen to @kleopatra. Also i think JSplitPane will only add more problems to your table and you should implement resizing yourself. How do you want to use Split pane, do you want to nest split panes?

Answer (score 3):

To me this looks like you want to use a JTable to layout Swing components much like using a HTML table to layout a page (which is not a good idea nowdays).

If this is true [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) (without using [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html)s) is your friend. If you want to have something like an Excel table you should use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

There are plenty of good [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) about all the Swing components from oracle.

Comment: ok, thanks. That's seems to be a bad ideea to start a topic on this idea.
I'll start to learn how use JTable and the table models.
Thanks.